# PHP check if isset one of the two

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I am trying to check both inputs but when only one of the two is set it should give TRUE.
when both are empty it should give a error.

```
      //check if post image upload or youtube url isset
      $pyturl = $_POST['post_yturl'];
      if (isset($_FILES['post_image']) && isset($pyturl)) {     
        if (empty($_FILES['post_image']['name']) or empty($pyturl)) {
          $errors = '<div class="error2">Choose a news header.</div>';

         } else {   
          //check image format                                                                                                    
           $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); 
           $file_name = $_FILES['post_image']['name']; 
           $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
           $file_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
```

Tried multiple things but it doesnt want to work as i want.

Comment: Have you tried `||` (or) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if any fields in a form are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250880/how-to-check-if-any-fields-in-a-form-are-empty)

Comment: You have 2 if statements which clobber each other. Remove your first if statement and use `||` (or).

Comment: Try `if (isset($_FILES['post_image']) || isset($pyturl)) {...`

Comment: @waterloomatt this results in a error when one of the 2 are set.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani this is helpful but does not answer my question, i am trying to check  one of the two is set, if so it has to result true. if both are empty it should give false

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative (and cleaner IMHO) is to do your validation upfront and then process it once you know you have valid data.

When you start processing, you'll also need to check which source your need to process - `$_FILE` Vs. `$_POST`

```
<?php

$isValid = true;

// Validation - if both sources are empty, validation should fail. 
if (!isset($_FILES['post_image']) && !isset($_POST['post_yturl'])) {
    $isValid = false;
    $errors = '<div class="error2">Choose a news header.</div>';
}

... More validation if needed

if ($isValid) {

    // At this point you know you have at least 1 source. Start processing. 

    if (isset($_FILES['post_image']) {
        ... do your processing
    }

    if (isset($_POST['post_yturl']) {
        ... do your processing
    }
}
```